# Complicated Argument in Signature of C Function

Tags: c

I was told to make the signature of my function:

```
int foo(void(*x) (void*, void*), void *arg1, void *arg2, void *stack)
```

What is the first argument representing? I would appreciate it if somebody could explain it with a concrete example.

Comment: Do you know [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=void%28*x%29+%28void*%2C+void*%29%3B)?

Comment: @Gerhardh A.k.a "the syntax error for valid C generator"...

Comment: @Lundin yes, unfortunately it doesn't work in many situations but I think it is worth giving it a try. At least when it creates a response, I haven't seen a wrong one yet.

Answer (score 2):

It's a function pointer given the name `x`. It points to a function that takes two void pointers are arguments and returns `void`.

You might make this easier to understand by using `typedef`.

```
typedef void (*funcptr)(void*, void*);

int foo(funcptr x, void *arg1, void *arg2, void *stack) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I would rather recommend not hiding pointers behind typedef, so instead: `typedef void func (void*, void*);` ... `int foo (func* x, ...)`